# Generate LINQ dynamically

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, expression

I want to sort the data in txt file and for this I am using LINQ below...

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(fileInfo.FullName)
            .Select(x => x.Split('|').Reverse().ToArray())
            .OrderBy(x => x[0])
            .ThenBy(x => x[1])
            .Select(x => string.Join("|", x));
```

The problem with this is, this is limited to only index 0 and 1 for sorting.

I want to pass column indexes from outside (user input) and then construct the LINQ query. There could be 1 column to sort or multiple columns.

Can anyone help me with constructing this type of linq at runtime and get the result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like that:

```
public void DoIt(int[] sortIndexes) 
{
    var lines = File.ReadLines(fileInfo.FullName)
            .Select(x => x.Split('|').Reverse().ToArray())
            .OrderBy(x => 0);

    foreach (int index in sortIndexes) 
    {
        lines = lines.ThenBy(x => x[index]);
    }

    lines = lines.Select(x => string.Join("|", x));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Dynamic LINQ](http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/). It's available from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library/) and the project website.

The syntax is slightly different than what you put above, but very close `.OrderBy(x[1])`